# How to assign string | undefined to string in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined, aurelia

I want to assign a variable, which is string | undefined, to a string variable, as you see here:

```
private selectedSerialForReplace(): string | undefined {
    return this.selectedSerials.pop();
  }

luminaireReplaceLuminaire(params: {  "serial": string; "newserial": string; }, options?: any): FetchArgs {
............
}

luminaireReplaceLuminaire({serial: this.selectedSerialForReplace(), newserial: response.output});
```

I get this error:

> Argument of type '{ serial: string | undefined; newserial: any; }' is
>   not assignable to parameter of type '{ "serial": string; "newserial":
>   string; }'

I cannot change selectedSerialForReplace() function to return anything else. Could you please help me?

Comment: Please try to improve your [MCVE] with reproducible code. What is the logic behind `luminaireReplaceLuminaire`? Is it supposed to accept undefined "serial" parameters?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The typescript compiler performs strict null checks, which means you can't pass a `string | undefined` variable into a method that expects a `string`.

To fix this you have to perform an explicit check for `undefined` before calling `luminaireReplaceLuminaire()`.

In your example:

```
private selectedSerialForReplace(): string | undefined {
    return this.selectedSerials.pop();
}

luminaireReplaceLuminaire(params: {  "serial": string; "newserial": string; }, options?: any): FetchArgs {
    ............
}

const serial = this.selectedSerialForReplace();
if(serial !== undefined) {
    luminaireReplaceLuminaire({serial, newserial: response.output});
}
```

Comment: Side note, it's important to use `!=` when checking `undefined` to catch `null` as well. `null == undefined` is `true`, `null === undefined` is `false`

Answer (score 37):

If you are sure that serial could not be `undefined` you can use the [`!` post-fix operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

```
luminaireReplaceLuminaire({serial: this.selectedSerialForReplace()!, newserial: response.output});
```

Comment: any quick solution if it's array of `[string | undefined ]` to `[ string ]`