# Type not inferred when accessed as object key

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following example:

```js
type Dictionary = {
  [key: string] : string | undefined
}

function greet(name: string) {
  return 'Hello ' + name + '!';
}

function callGreetError(key: string, d: Dictionary) {
  if (typeof d[key] !== 'undefined') {
    return greet(d[key]) // TS Error: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
  }
  return key + ' is not in dictionary';
}

function callGreetNoError(key: string, d: Dictionary) {
  const storedVal = d[key];
  if (typeof storedVal !== 'undefined') {
    return greet(storedVal) // Error goes away when value is stored in an external var.
  }
  return key + ' is not in dictionary';
}
```

I'm trying to understand why on `callGreetError` the type of `d[key]` inside the `if` block isn't inferred to be a `string` even though I'm explicitly telling TS it isn't `undefined`.

And why storing the value of `d[key]` on an external var `storedVal` on `callGreetNoError` fixes this error.

Comment: Have you tried `d[key] !== undefined` instead?

Comment: don;t check the type, check the value and it should work

Comment: Yes, same issue.. checking for a value instead of a type doesn't fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign string | undefined to string in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194964/how-to-assign-string-undefined-to-string-in-typescript)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski - I don't see how it does..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically TS won't narrow the property access type of [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) like `key`.

```
const d: Dictionary = {...};
const key = "foo";
const fooProp = d[key];

// using .length as string type check
d["foo"] !== undefined && d["foo"].length; // ✔
fooProp !== undefined && fooProp.length; // ✔
d[key] !== undefined && d[key].length; // error, possibly undefined
```

It is *not*, because TS does some mutability check and warns that `d[key]` value could have changed between the check and its usage. For example following code is perfectly fine for the compiler, but may throw at run-time:

```
const testDict: Dictionary = {
  get foo() { return Math.random() > 0.5 ? "hey" : undefined }
};

function callGreetError(d: Dictionary) {
  // compiles fine, but throws error at run-time from time to time
  if (d["foo"] !== undefined) d["foo"].length
}
callGreetError(testDict)
```

To allow proper variable narrowing with [control flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis), TS must clearly know, what property you mean: by property access with dot notation `d.foo` or with bracket notation and a literal like `d["foo"]`.

The "trick" with `const storedVal = d[key]` works, because TS infers the variable type of `storedVal` to be `string | undefined`. As control flow analysis in general is based on variables, the compiler now has an easier time narrowing down `storedVal` with a check for `undefined`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=25&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgY2HA9gOwIYCcRQLxQDeAUFFANoDWEIAXFAM7BZxoDmAuvUy+1AD5QArmgAmEAGasIo4gF9ixBOiZRR9eElSYc+IlABEElCgP0DAI2wGANIasAvM8LGTpoqHIDcSlcCjUuARGJgY+ymiqxigAClgoYHqiVDQcPsQA9BnCDKxsUAB0ADYQ7MAAFlAYDIzMeVCgkFAI5RAIlMTJIaYcUACEeAQi4lJoMlAAZBNq5N0GHMWlbBVeUFlQgCjkxNFxCf2DLiPuk9M78WCLZeWr61vJgb0DQ66j41MzD5fL12vZEFjxLB2MAoBi5CxFXDDNxjWS+SL+YAQJiaYAaRDIdDYIJEUhQNgQfzRAAUAEp9FhCUIsGgoABZDAVApYDBiFAAWzJUAAfFAAAwFACsUAA-IZWiADFB6NDXh4FN5FBIRFp0M0MEUigBxSmEgCiAJQWGJ6lgGO02PJJDI62U7LAcBKNVedgsQkR5XiAHcav9AVV-FgRABaZDs6ASeLshpwcMNFAx8N4uASKAm2bReb7Z5HWHkrqZhYlK7yJQa7W64AGwHEpEojGk4hAA)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a temporary variable so you are not accessing the value separately every time. For all typescript knows the value could have changed between the check and its use:

```
function callGreetError(key: string, d: Dictionary) {
  const temp = d[key];
  if (temp !== undefined) {
    return greet(temp)
  }
  return key + ' is not in dictionary';
}
```

In this case both checks `typeof temp !== "undefined"` and `temp !== undefined` would work

The simplest example showing the problem can be manually assigning a get operator to the dictionary key. In the code sample below you can see that the value of key would be indeed always a string, satisfying type requirements, however it changes with every access

```
const testDict: Dictionary = {};

Object.defineProperty(testDict, "key", {
  get() { return Math.random().toString() }
});

console.log(testDict.key);
console.log(testDict.key);
```

Thus checking the type with first access and using it with the second is unrelated

Comment: Interesting, I think this is the answer I have been looking for - however, this is clearly a synchronous scenario.. Can't TS tell that?

Comment: @itaydafna i edited my answer to include an example typescript is warning you about

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski it is a reasonable idea, that TS could warn about a potential value change of `d[key]` between its check and usage. But here it is because of the compiler's inability to narrow the property access type in combination with a computed property `key` (made up an answer).

Comment: I'm approving @ford04's answer, as it perfectly answers my questions as well as explains what's flawed in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an **!** to d[key] in the return statement tells TypeScript that d[key] will not be undefined in this case, although normally it can be. This is known as a [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html).

```
function callGreetError(key: string, d: Dictionary) {
  if (typeof d[key] !== 'undefined') {
    return greet(d[key]!) 
  }
  return key + ' is not in dictionary';
}
```

> A new ! post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its
>   operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type
>   checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation
>   x! produces a value of the type of x with null and undefined excluded.
>   Similar to type assertions of the forms x and x as T, the !
>   non-null assertion operator is simply removed in the emitted
>   JavaScript code.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it like this:

```
function callGreetError(key: string, d: Dictionary) {
  return d?.[key]
    ? greet(d[key])
    : key + ' is not in dictionary';
}
```

This way you're making sure that `key` is not undefined, and not only `d[key]`. If the syntax confuses you, you can read more about optional chaining [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).