# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'xxx' with if else on parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

anyone know how I can fix the following? I will have the error from vscode/webstorm `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'`
I have one customize function only accept one parameter with string type and I using if/else to filter out the parameter from undefined or string, but I still get the error `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'`
what is the best way for me to fix it?

```
function abc(value: string | number) {
    console.log(value)
}

abc(typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : 'dummy string')
abc(0) // 0
abc(1) // 1
abc('') // ''
```

Comment: How is `x` declared?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45195136/2299362) is what you're looking for. You're declaring an explicit type for `value`, and `undefined` is not part of those types.

Comment: @Taplar that is my main question, I should not affect 0

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hu3scnwr/  I'm not seeing that error replicated.

Comment: There isn't an if / else in your code example, so I'm guessing you've written a simpler snippet to explain the problem you're having. Unfortunately the simpler snippet does not replicate the issue.